# Seeking source (and other solutions): If $a^{1/p}+c^{1/p}\leq b^{1/p}$ and $u^{1/(p+1)}+w^{1/(p+1)}\geq v^{1/(p+1)}$, then $ubc-vca+wab \ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, holder-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $u$, $v$, $w$, and $p$ all be positive real numbers, and
> $$a^{1/p}+c^{1/p}\leq b^{1/p},\quad u^{1/(p+1)}+w^{1/(p+1)}\geq v^{1/(p+1)}$$
> Prove that $ubc-vca+wab \ge 0$.

My answer:
$$acv\leq ac(u^{\frac{1}{p+1}}+w^{\frac{1}{p+1}})^{p+1}=[(uc)^{\frac{1}{p+1}}a^{\frac{1}{p+1}}+(wa)^{\frac{1}{p+1}}c^{\frac{1}{p+1}}]^{p+1}$$

By Hölder's inequality, $$[(uc)^{\frac{1}{p+1}}a^{\frac{1}{p+1}}+(wa)^{\frac{1}{p+1}}c^{\frac{1}{p+1}}]^{p+1}\leq (uc+wa)(a^{\frac{1}{p}}+c^{\frac{1}{p}})\leq (uc+wa)b.$$
Done!

It is easy to see that this problem is related to Schur's inequality. I am finding its source (maybe from Olympiad) and its other answers.

Comment: A typo in the rightmost of your Holder line. We may use Holder in this way: $(u/a + w/c)b \ge (u/a + w/c)(a^{1/p} + c^{1/p})^p \ge (u^{1/(p+1)} + v^{1/(p+1)})^{p+1} \ge v$.